# is their any way where i can view my HTML code into frame (selenium webdriver and Java)

Tags: html, selenium, iframe, frame

I am automating an Application which contains many embedded iframes in it. So is there any way where i can view my HTML source code in frames ?

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the element(or frame) with **Firebug** in **Firefox** ?

Comment: Yes Subh i tried and using it ..But my HTML code contains so many nested frames. so i am looking for any online tool like JSON viewer but in my case i should be able to view frames in it.

Comment: You can also add an [addon **Firepath**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firepath/) to the **Firebug**. It can help you out too.

Comment: @Subh : Thanks i tried it, but could not find frames in my HTML code. Can you suggest me some other website or Add-on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try Link  [HTML code Beautify](http://codebeautify.org/htmlviewer/) where you can view your HTML code in more pleasant way.I have the same problem with frame and i use this Link to check the frames and close the unwanted frames. In may case i have to switch like 3 -4 frames to get the the desired web-element. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your help Rupesh.Yes i can view my HTML better now but do you any other website which can show the HTML as per frames?